# Trying to make a to-do-list using react

Tags: reactjs

[image]

After adding the item into the input, when clicking the button to add the items on the list, its only creating the li element and the user input is not there.

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      userInput: "",
      list: []
    };
  }

  changeUserInput = Input => {
    this.setState({ userInput: Input.target.value });
  };
  onButtonSubmit = Input => {
    let listArray = this.state.list;
    listArray.push(Input);
    this.setState({ list: listArray });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Input
          changeUserInput={this.changeUserInput}
          onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}
        />
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.map((val, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{val}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

//Input.js

const Input = ({ changeUserInput, onButtonSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p className="f2">{"Make a shopping list by adding items"}</p>
      <div>
        <input
          className="w-70 ma2 pa2 br-pill"
          type="text"
          placeholder="enter items"
          onChange={changeUserInput}
        />
        <div>
          <button
            className="f6 grow br-pill ba bw1 ph3 pv2 mb2 dib black
    pointer"
            onClick={() => {
              onButtonSubmit();
            }}
          >
            Add Item
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

1. List item

   expected the output like
   .Item
   but the out put is only
   .

Answer (score 2):

You are directly mutating the state, which you should never do.

As you already have input change handler, your submit function should be,

```
onButtonSubmit = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState, 
    list:prevState.list.concat(this.state.userInput),
    userInput:''
  }
  ),()=>console.log(this.state))
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-86opq8)

Answer (score 1):

Always treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.
Your should not modify array by appending values in it.

Try below approach:

```
const { list } = this.state;
const newList = [...list, Input]
this.setState({ list: newList })
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `onButtonSubmit` function you are trying to add `Input` in the list but you should add `this.state.userInput`

```
onButtonSubmit = () => {
  this.setState({list: [...this.state.list, this.state.userInput]})
}
```

Edit: As mentioned in other answers, it's safer to use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as it is not mutating the original array but creating a new one.

Comment: well, just pushing to the same reference is a bit dangerous here, there [Mukesh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57388272/3231537) is on point

Comment: Yes totally agree with you on this point. I'll edit my answer to use spread operator instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending a parameter to your `onButtonSubmit` function, if you look at this:

```
<button 
  className= 'f6 grow br-pill ba bw1 ph3 pv2 mb2 dib blackpointer' 
  onClick ={() => {onButtonSubmit()}} >Add Item</button>
```

There is no argument supplied, however, you do expect one here:

```
onButtonSubmit = (Input) => {
  let listArray = this.state.list;
  listArray.push(Input);
  this.setState({list: listArray})
}
```

More interestingly, the change handler, you set the current user input value here:

```
changeUserInput = (Input) => {
  this.setState({userInput: Input.target.value});
}
```

So your submission, should probably be more like

```
onButtonSubmit = () => {
  let listArray = [...this.state.list, this.state.userInput];
  this.setState({ list: listArray, userInput: undefined })
}
```

Where you would create a new array from the current list state, add the new userInput value and then update the state (and reset the current user input)